# How to get brightcove video playing for Chrome over https

Tags: google-chrome, video, https, brightcove

We're using brightcove as 3rd party vendor to host videos. For one of our applications we run our site over https and have started to develop to integrate linking to video via a dialog box from the main page.  We tried an iframing the https video short url and then tried to put the html right on the dialog page jsp as advised in here: [publishing video on https](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/publishing-video-cloud-player-https-page)

Similar errors about insecure content get hit because it references http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/... etc.   which is not available via https.

The support reference even indicates that Chrome and Flash do not support this. Has anyone run into this and what exactly is the workaround?  Chrome's the preferred browser of choice, so advising to launch in another browser won't fly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you are including correctly the library? We did it successfuly, remember the very first thing to change is:

**https :// sadmin**

```
... <script src="https://sadmin.brightcove .... >
```

not

```
... <script src="http://admin.brightcove .... >
```

We had to do it in a page which runs under https (facebook). You can check it here: https://www.facebook.com/LaVanguardia/app_128953167177144

This is our code:

```
<!--
By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C 
found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/. 
-->

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://sadmin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>


<object id="myExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="secureConnections" value="true" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="500" />
  <param name="height" value="900" />
  <param name="playerID" value="xxxxxxxx" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />

</object>
```

However, a link to your code would be clearer.

Regards,

Eduard Roura

Comment: You also need `<param name="secureHTMLConnections" value="true" />`